# How can I iterate a JSON in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, json

So I have a JSON variable with several values like this:

`"["1", "2", "3", "4"]"`

What i need to do is pass that value to an SQL procedure to mount a query in which the WHERE clause adds all the values in the JSON, so something like parsing the JSON, interate it and concat it in order to get an @where similar to:

`AND id=1 AND id=2 AND id=3 AND id=4`

I tried something like this, as something really similar is taking place in an already existing procedure, but doesn't work:

```
SET @idWhere="";

IF id IS NOT NULL AND JSON_EXTRACT(id, '$[0]') IS NOT NULL THEN
    SET @idWhere = CONCAT(@idWhere," AND JSON_SEARCH('",id,"','one',id) IS NOT NULL ");
END IF;
```

Where id is both the name of the JSON and the column name.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Read about SQL sentence `IN` [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/in.php)

Comment: can you share your sample json data?

Comment: The sample JSON data is exactly what i posted:

```"["1", "2", "3", "4"]"```

Comment: Edit: ok not exactly, it may vary the numbers, have more, have less, but the organization is exactly like that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use `json_table()` to turn the array to a recordset, and then aggregate the results with `group_concat()`:

```
select group_concat(concat('id = ', i) separator ' and ') id_where
from json_table(
    '["1", "2", "3", "4"]',
    "$[*]" columns(i int path '$')
) as t
```

In this **[demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/k9bRnNUE6qpBts6djMXArT/1)**, this yields:

```
| id_where                                |
| --------------------------------------- |
| id = 1 and id = 2 and id = 3 and id = 4 |
```

NB: you probably want `or`s, not `and`s.